# Navbar not pushing content below it down when expanding

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

When I switch to mobile mode on my website and press the button to expand the menu, it expands but it overlaps the content below the menu and is not readable. How to I make it so that it pushes the content below down?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('home') }}">
            <img src="logo.png" height="75px">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>text</a>  </li>
                <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i>text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-tag"></i>text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-rss"></i>text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i>text</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Language <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="{{ route('switch_language', 'en') }}">English</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please strip your code down to a [mcve], then make it a runnable snippet with all the relevant scripts & styles included

Comment: looks like you are using boostrap. i would suggest you look into their examples https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar-static-top/ and see how they setup their page to accomplish that behaviour